# How to pass DOM element to JS function - Node cannot be found in the current page error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass an element to another function and use it in jQuery as a DOM element:

```
$(document).on('change', selector, function() {
    element = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success: function (jsonData) {            
            myFunction(element);
        }
    });
});
```

```
function myFunction(element) {
    $(element);
}
```

The `element` is sent, I can get all the data from it, but it seems that it's not linked to the element in the page:

[image]

I can't use `$(element).closest('form')` for example.

---

EDIT:
I was trying to post a jsfiddle with an example, but I couldn't reproduce it. After testing it harder, I found my mistake ‍♂️. Before executing myFunction I was replacing these elements (including the caller) with the AJAX response, but the structure was the same so I didn't think about it at first sight, because I could find the element using the selector.

Comment: declare the variable so it is not global `const element = this;`

Comment: @epascarello same error :(

Comment: I was not expecting that to fix it. Question is pretty hard for us to know what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear what's the problem you are encountering.

As far as I can say, that code should work as expected despite a couple details that I'd prefer was crafted differently.

For example I prefer to grab the element triggering an event using the `.target` property of the event passed to the handler function instead of using `this`. Also the `target` (that's how I renamed it) variable belonging to the scope of the change event retains its value when evaluated in the callback invoked by the ajax process when the request will be fulfilled but it would be better factored passing a `bound` function as an argument to `$.ajax()`.

Anwyay those are just recommendation to better factor code...

Your code should already work correctly as expected as showing here.

The `selector` here is statically passed as the `input` literal so that a change event handler will be attached to all input elements in the document.
Plus I changed your `success` callback to be performed on `complete` instead because as you can see I used a bogus url for the ajax request.

When you give focus to a text input and change its value, after moving the focus elsewhere, the change event will fire and the `myFunction` call will print out the element triggering the change event and any of its parent info that will show the evidence that such element is attached to the dom.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input', function(event) {        
    //const target = event.target;
    target = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://bogusurl.com',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        complete: function (jsonData) {            
            myFunction(target);
        }
    });
});

function myFunction(element) {        
  console.log(`ChangedElement: ${element.id}`);
  console.log(`ImParent data attr from parent: ${$(element).closest('.parent').data('imparent')}`);  
  console.log(`parent form action: ${$(element).closest('form').attr('action')}`);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="nexturl">
  <div class="parent" data-imparent="yes">
    <input id="text1" placeholder="text1">
    <input id="text2" placeholder="text2">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I was trying to post a jsfiddle with an example, but I couldn't reproduce it. After testing it harder, I found my mistake ‍♂️. Before executing `myFunction` I was replacing these elements (including the caller) with the AJAX response, but the structure was the same so I didn't think about it at first sight, because I could find the element using the selector.